# Volume Slider Issue (HTML5 video)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Volume Slider is not showing on Chrome, there's only mute and unmute option. It's working on other browsers.

My code:

```html
<video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-fluid vjs-big-play-centered" controlsList="nodownload" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}"> @*
  <source src="@Model.VideoLink" type="video/mp4">*@ @*Testing Video*@ 
  <source src="clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"; data-value="dgdfdf" type='video/mp4' /> 
  <p> Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video. </p> 
</video>
```

Comment: Hello :). Can you show us your code? Without I'm afraid it's impossible to help you.

Comment: You have already been pointed to [ask] in response to your first question, so please go read it already!

Comment: @CBroe Alright.

Comment: @CodeF0x 

  <video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-fluid vjs-big-play-centered" controlsList="nodownload" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}">
                    @*<source src="@Model.VideoLink" type="video/mp4">*@
                    
                    @*Testing Video*@
                    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" data-value="dgdfdf" type='video/mp4' />
                    <p>
                        Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
                    </p>
                </video>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding **controls**

```
<video  src='https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4' controls>
</video>
```